# HDMI stopped working 18.04

Tags: 18.04, screen, hdmi, output

I have:
Intel® HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2)
on Asus X554L laptop

I have problems with HDMI at Ubuntu 18.04
I connected my TV with it, and it was working for some time, then it stopped, the device(TV) isn't shown.
I tried solutions posted in other questions, but they don't work for me.

I believe that the problem is with some wrong config(config in irregular state), but I don't know where to find this screen output config or how to reset it.
Ubuntu reinstall fixes this, but not permanently.

I had similar problem little before this with HDMI audio:

Some apps produced sound, some didn't (it was weird)
But then I found solution to install Pulse audio and switch each app sound output to laptop sound so it would work (it remained stuck with, some apps had sound output set to HDMI even HDMI was not connected).
But that fixed the sound problem.

I sometimes use laptop as laptop, and sometimes I have it connected to the TV(via HDMI) and have wireless keyboard, so I can use it like a smarter TV (PC from sofa/bed).

And I believe that some case corrupted screen output data, similar like the audio described above.

In period of week or more the laptop was on/off/suspended, the TV was on and off, the HDMI was connected and disconnected, the laptop lid was closed(without suspension-while showing on TV), the laptop was changing output screen normally by `fn+F8` and by all this actions in lot of different orders I believe corrupted the screen output data
Where to find and configure that data?

> ```
>  xrandr
> ```

```
   Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
    eDP-1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 345mm x 194mm
       1366x768      60.00*+
       1360x768      59.80    59.96  
       1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
       1024x768      60.04    60.00  
       960x720       60.00  
       928x696       60.05  
       896x672       60.01  
       1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
       960x600       59.93    60.00  
       960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
       800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
       840x525       60.01    59.88  
       864x486       59.92    59.57  
       800x512       60.17  
       700x525       59.98  
       800x450       59.95    59.82  
       640x512       60.02  
       720x450       59.89  
       700x450       59.96    59.88  
       640x480       60.00    59.94  
       720x405       59.51    58.99  
       684x384       59.88    59.85  
       680x384       59.80    59.96  
       640x400       59.88    59.98  
       576x432       60.06  
       640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
       512x384       60.00  
       512x288       60.00    59.92  
       480x270       59.63    59.82  
       400x300       60.32    56.34  
       432x243       59.92    59.57  
       320x240       60.05  
       360x202       59.51    59.13  
       320x180       59.84    59.32  
    DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

> lspci | grep VGA

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
```

[image]